# after using for loop all my column graphs are plotted in single color i need each bar in different color in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image]
[image]

```
$.getJSON("json/slide6_chart1.json", function(json) {
    var len = json.length;                              
    for(i=0;i<len; i++){                                      
            options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];  
            j = i-1;                         
            options.series[j] = json[i];                    
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);  
        };
```

Comment: can you please correct the code snippet (for loop not closed) ? Also, a jsfiddle/reproductible example (with data) would be nice if you want our help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are using same configuration object for all of your charts created in a loop.

```
const colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors
const option = {
  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    type: 'column',
    color: colors[0]
  }]
}
const options = []
for (let i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
  option.series[0].color = colors[i]
  options[i] = option
    //options[i] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(option)) // Clone object
}
for (let i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
  Highcharts.chart('chart' + i, options[i])
}
```

Live example:
https://jsfiddle.net/q7x1Lecg/

Answer (score 0):

Set the colorByPoint option to true and define the color sequence that you want.

```
options = {
chart: {...},
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        colorByPoint: true
    }
},
colors: [
    '#ff0000',
    '#00ff00',
    '#0000ff'
]}
```